# How to copy data from a stream while also forwarding a stream

Tags: rust, hyper

I am using [hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper) 0.12 to build a proxy service. When receiving a response body from the upstream server I want to forward it back to the client ASAP, **and** save the contents in a buffer for later processing.

So I need a function that:

- takes a [`Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) (a [`hyper::Body`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.12.7/hyper/struct.Body.html), to be precise)
- returns a `Stream` that is functionally identical to the input stream
- **also** returns some sort of `Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = ...>` that is resolved with the buffered contents of the input stream, when the output stream is completely consumed

I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I guess the function I'm looking for will look something like this:

```
type BufferFuture = Box<Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = ()>>;
pub fn copy_body(body: hyper::Body) -> (hyper::Body, BufferFuture) {
    let body2 = ... // ???
    let buffer = body.fold(Vec::<u8>::new(), |mut buf, chunk| {
        buf.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
        // ...somehow send this chunk to body2 also?
    });
    (body2, buffer);
}
```

Below is what I have tried, and it works until `send_data()` fails (obviously).

```
type BufferFuture = Box<Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = ()>>;
pub fn copy_body(body: hyper::Body) -> (hyper::Body, BufferFuture) {
    let (mut sender, body2) = hyper::Body::channel();
    let consume =
        body.map_err(|_| ()).fold(Vec::<u8>::new(), move |mut buf, chunk| {
            buf.extend_from_slice(&chunk);

            // What to do if this fails?
            if sender.send_data(chunk).is_err() {}
            Box::new(future::ok(buf))
        });

    (body2, Box::new(consume));
}
```

However, something tells me I am on the wrong track.

I have found [`Sink.fanout()`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html#method.fanout) which seems like it is what I want, but I do not have a `Sink`, and I don't know how to construct one. `hyper::Body` implements `Stream` but not `Sink`.

Comment: What behavior should happen if the second future is polled before the first stream finishes?

Comment: I would try to [Stream.map()](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.23/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.map) the body. The buffer will only be filled when the stream is consumed, but if you want to send the stream quickly that's what you need to do anyway.

Comment: @Shepmaster Then the future should not yet be ready; it should be completed only once the entire stream was read or passed though.

Comment: @JanHudec How can I then return a future that completes once the stream is finished while at the same time returning said stream back to hyper? It seems al related methods consume the stream...

Comment: @molf, that's what I am not sure. I think you need one or the other side to do manage the pulling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I ended up doing was implement a new type of stream that does what I need. This appeared to be necessary because `hyper::Body` does not implement `Sink` nor does `hyper::Chunk` implement `Clone` (which is required for `Sink.fanout()`), so I cannot use any of the existing combinators.

First a struct that contains all details that we need and methods to append a new chunk, as well as notify that the buffer is completed.

```
struct BodyClone<T> {
    body: T,
    buffer: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    sender: Option<futures::sync::oneshot::Sender<Vec<u8>>>,
}

impl BodyClone<hyper::Body> {
    fn flush(&mut self) {
        if let (Some(buffer), Some(sender)) = (self.buffer.take(), self.sender.take()) {
            if sender.send(buffer).is_err() {}
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, chunk: &hyper::Chunk) {
        use hyper::body::Payload;

        let length = if let Some(buffer) = self.buffer.as_mut() {
            buffer.extend_from_slice(chunk);
            buffer.len() as u64
        } else {
            0
        };

        if let Some(content_length) = self.body.content_length() {
            if length >= content_length {
                self.flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I implemented the `Stream` trait for this struct.

```
impl Stream for BodyClone<hyper::Body> {
    type Item = hyper::Chunk;
    type Error = hyper::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> futures::Poll<Option<Self::Item>, Self::Error> {
        match self.body.poll() {
            Ok(Async::Ready(Some(chunk))) => {
                self.push(&chunk);
                Ok(Async::Ready(Some(chunk)))
            }
            Ok(Async::Ready(None)) => {
                self.flush();
                Ok(Async::Ready(None))
            }
            other => other,
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I could define an extension method on `hyper::Body`:

```
pub type BufferFuture = Box<Future<Item = Vec<u8>, Error = ()> + Send>;

trait CloneBody {
    fn clone_body(self) -> (hyper::Body, BufferFuture);
}

impl CloneBody for hyper::Body {
    fn clone_body(self) -> (hyper::Body, BufferFuture) {
        let (sender, receiver) = futures::sync::oneshot::channel();

        let cloning_stream = BodyClone {
            body: self,
            buffer: Some(Vec::new()),
            sender: Some(sender),
        };

        (
            hyper::Body::wrap_stream(cloning_stream),
            Box::new(receiver.map_err(|_| ())),
        )
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
let (body: hyper::Body, buffer: BufferFuture) = body.clone_body();
```